# Javascript regex match and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have currently this type of regex replacement function

```
var regex = new RegExp(value, 'gi');

var return = item.replace(regex, function(match) { return "<strong>" + match + "</strong>" });
```

e.g.

```
value = 'a';
```

where

```
item = 'Cat Dog Apple';
```

It returns = 'C**a**t Dog **A**pple';

What I want

- match only at start of word
- match non-case sensitive
- make strong whole word, not only letter

So result should be

```
Cat Dog '<strong>Apple</strong>'
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: What do you mean by only at start of word?

Comment: @ALFA at the beginning of word. Jan's reply is correct but still minor mistake pls see my comment in Jan's solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for

```
\ba\w+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8kwSfg/1/).

---

In `JavaScript`:

```js
let items = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Apple', 'advertisement', 'New York'];
let regex = /\ba\w+/gi;

items.forEach(function(item) {
    let new_item = item.replace(regex, function(match) {
        return "<strong>" + match + "</strong>";
    });
    console.log(new_item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but still minor issues. I needed string not an array so I removed array, but pls help resolve following.

You have passed matching string as string within regex, I need to pass variable within regex.

Second It's not matching whole word, say if I pass 'do' it's making <strong>Dog</strong> but If I pass 'dog' it's not converting Dog to <strong>Dog</strong>

Comment: Please read my above comment.

I think I have got the solution

var regex = "\\b"+testString+"\\w+|\\b"+testString;

regex = new RegExp(regex, 'gi');

let new_item = givenString.replace(regex, function(match) {
      return "<strong>" + match + "</strong>";
  });

If you think there can be better and faster regex, please suggest. Thank you